# Setting carrier per product

Tags: e-commerce

I'm working on a store that has two types of products: perishable food and general merchandise.  The food must always be shipped overnight via FedEx, and the other merchandise must always be shipped via USPS.  If somebody orders products from both categories, they must be shipped separately.

Do you know of an existing module or configuration settings that would allow for this?

If not, it sounds like a custom module would be the other solution.  In this case, what is the best approach?  I'm thinking it would be splitting the order into a multi-address shipment, using the same address for both but with different shipping methods.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this programatically, so any tutorials/samples/resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the **sanest** way to handle this would be to create two orders per product type, each shipping with a different carrier to the same address. This also IMO makes more sense from a stores tracking perspective as you can handle each independently from each other.

To get you on the right track(since Magento is especially cryptic in this part of itself) you should read the [Inchoo programmatically create order in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/) post and by the same author [Programatically create customer and order in Magento with full blown one page checkout](http://activecodeline.net/programatically-create-customer-and-order-in-magento-with-full-blown-one-page-checkout-process-under-the-hood).

Basically as I see this going is:

1. Get the customer order
2. Itinerate through each product inside the order and split it up in two arrays for each product type
3. Create a separate order for each product type and use the different shipping methods for each.

You will probably have to extend a some controllers OR do it the non-standard way and use helper functions for this, the hard parts will be integrating the payment/shipping modules inside your order process. Going this way will have you creating the full checkout process as the one page checkout Magento provides won't really work and is too much pain to get to work because of the way it uses AJAX.

Also another alternative is to hook in to Magento's pre-create order events and create the orders there using already defined order data split it up in two orders, but this is something I never heard or saw implemented at the moment so you'd have to do it "blindfolded" so to speak.

An easier approach would be to use a custom field that defines your product's shipping method, this way you just add that and don't care about custom orders. You just react with that, however tracking will become mostly impossible IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and links to the resources!  Although your idea does make sense and would solve the problem, I'm not sure it's the right solution for this store, as one-page checkout and purchasing both at once is a must for this site.  That said, I think I may try a variation of your idea, but instead of creating separate orders in step 3, just split them into different shipments on the Shipping section of checkout based on the type of product.

Comment: Actually, it looks like multi-shipping doesn't even use onepage checkout, so that argument is invalid :P  The more that I think about it, the more I think your approach makes sense.  My only question is this: how do I handle charging the customer?  Is there a safe/easy way to charge them once for both orders combined, or will there be two separate charges?

Comment: As you will be in charge of the whole checkout process you can charge them once for both. This would just be a backend thing for you, you already have to rewrite the checkout process to sort through both orders, the simplest thing to do would be to charge ONCE for the big order with the whole products, then split them up into two "sub-orders" for each shipping address. There are a lot of ways to go through this but you need to find one that the store is comfortable with, however this is the only approach I can see that would give you the needed flexibility in managing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Over-ride the Free Shipping module.

You can setup a sales rule that applies to certain products and makes them 'Free Shipping', leaving the other products to your chosen main shipment provider.

You will need to see how this works, however, the point is that Magento does have something built in to split an order into two shipping categories, albeit only a sales rule on free shipping. But you have source code...